# What's known about the matroid induced by the Plücker coordinates of the representation of a matroid?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, grassmannians, matroid-theory, exterior-algebra

Let $M$ be a linear matroid with ground set $E$ and independent subsets $\mathcal I$, represented by $\rho: E \rightarrow V$.
This induces a map
$$
\hat\rho: \mathcal I \rightarrow \mathbf P(\Lambda V), \{e_1,\ldots,e_k\} \mapsto [\rho(e_1) \wedge \cdots \wedge \rho(e_k)].
$$
The subset $\operatorname{Im}(\hat\rho) \subset \mathbf P(\Lambda V)$ in turn defines a linear matroid $\hat M$ over $\Lambda V$.

Is there anything known about this matroid $\hat M$, e.g. how it depends on the choice of representation, and what its bases look like in relation to the bases of $M$? I'm interested in particular in the case where $M$ is uniform (for instance, I think the representation shouldn't matter in that case) or arises combinatorially, and would like to obtain combinatorial descriptions of $\hat M$. But any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your $\mathcal{I}$ the set of independent subset of $E$?

Comment: @user2520938 Yes; this is now reflected in the question.